# Mediawiki error after edit pages - "your browser do not support unicode"

Tags: mediawiki

I installed mediawiki on my cloud server with plesk. and manually updated the version from 1.31 to 1.37. But after I updated my mediawiki I can´t edit pages. After click on "save" I get this error message:

> It seems like your browser doesn't support Unicode. This is required to edit Pages, so your edit hasn't been published.

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Cause I had set up the server first I decided to re-install the system with no article.
Now it works after a clean install and upadte from version 1.31 to 1.37.1